# Make a request without submitting - PHP, AJAX & Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm still a beginner in PHP programming. I need help on how can I prompt the selected date. A simple webpage which allows user to choose date (via javascript) then after it clicks the submit button. I'd like to prompt the user of the date but what it does is open up a new page and displays the current page.

My PHP file: `rcl_stock_allocation.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="inc/style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="inc/cal_styles.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
        <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript" src="inc/myCalendar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function popCal(ThisValue){
                calpop  = new Epoch('epoch_popup','popup',document.getElementById(ThisValue));
                calpop.toggle();
            }
        </script>
        <title>RCL Stock Allocation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo "<form name='rcl_stock_allocation' action='' method='get' target=_blank >";
        echo "<table border = '0'>";
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><font size='2' ><b>RCL Stock Allocation for Bookshop</b></font></td></tr>";
        print "<tr><td></br></td></tr>";
        print <<<menu1
        <tr><td align=right >Date of Transaction</td><td> <input type="text" id ="transactionDate" name="transactionDate" class = graytextbox readonly=true style='width:80px; text-align:center' value = '$transactionDate' />&nbsp;<a href=# onclick="popCal('transactionDate');">&nbsp;Date Picker</a>

menu1;
        print "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='load_data' id='load_data' value='Load Stocks' /></td></tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</form>";
        //echo "lloyd";
        ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my javascript: `rcl_stkall.js`

```
$(function() {
            $('.error').hide();
            $(".load_data").click(function() {
                $('.error').hide();
                var transactionDate = $("input#transactionDate").val();
                if(transactionDate == ""){
                    $("label#transactionDate").show();
                    $("input#transactionDate").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                var dateOfTransaction = 'date=' + transactionDate;
                alert(dateOfTransaction); return false;
            });
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just FYI : While posting Questions on SO , its better to use only relevant part of source code. Other ways users need to research on your source code.

Comment: Your selector for the submit button is wrong, should be '#load_data' rather than '.load_data'. When you're troubleshooting something like this, make sure the event handler is firing when you expect it to fire using an alert or a breakpoint in firebug or chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are using id="load_data" for submit button so

try this,

$(".load_data").click(function() { should be

$("#load_data").click(function() {

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the basics:

When you start the form, remove 'target=_blank' - this isn't necessary.

Then you can stop the form from submitting by preventing the default submit action.
Add this to your JS within the '$(function() {'

```
$('#rcl_stock_allocation').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // add code here to show prompt the user of the date 
});
```

if you then need to submit the form after the user has being prompted of the date, use:

```
$('#rcl_stock_allocation').submit();
```

to complete sending the form.

Answer (score 0):

put type='button'

```
    <input type='button' name='load_data' id='load_data' value='Load Stocks' />
```